# How to access a field of a struct within a struct?

Tags: rust

I have a struct container of `Child`ren and a method `pop()` that removes the last added `Child` and returns it's `a` value:

```
struct Child {
    a: i32,
    b: String,
}

struct Container<'a> {
    vector: &'a mut Vec<Child>,
}

impl<'a> Container<'a> {
    fn pop(&mut self) -> i32 {
        return self.vector.pop().a;
    }
}
```

I get the error during compilation:

```
error: no field `a` on type `std::option::Option<Child>`
  --> src/main.rs:12:34
   |
12 |         return self.vector.pop().a;
   |                                  ^
```

Does the scope of `Container`'s `pop()` not allow access to values of its  `Child`ren's scope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Vec::pop` returns an `Option<Child>`, not a `Child`. This allows it to have something reasonable to return in case there are no elements in the `Vec` to pop off. To get at the `a` that may be inside, you can convert from `Option<Child>` to `Child` using `unwrap()`, but that will cause your program to [panic](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic!.html) if the `Vec` was empty. The code for that would look like this:

```
fn pop(&mut self) -> i32 {
    return self.vector.pop().unwrap().a;
}
```

Another option would be to more closely copy `Vec`'s behavior, and return `None` in case there are no elements. You could do that using `Option`'s [map method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.map):

```
fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
    return self.vector.pop().map(|child| child.a)
}
```

Comment: Great, I didn't pay attention to the Option type, I've just started playing with Rust. It's pretty cool! Thx.